How can I make this code more DRY
So I have some POCO classes like this:
public record Party
{
    public string? Location{ get; set; }
    public string? Guests{ get; set; }
    public string? Drinks{ get; set; }
}

and I have this struct which has many methods that are very very similar.
I wanted your idea on how can I write this with less copy-pasted code. Notice the pattern of those Make* methods are very similar**.
public struct NamedSet
{
    public NamedSet(string Name, string IdValue)
    {
        IdName = Name;
        Id = IdValue;
    }
    
    public static NamedSet MakeLocation(string? value)
    {
        const string name = nameof(Party.Location);
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? MakeBlank(name) : new NamedSet(name, value);
    }

    public static NamedSet MakeGuests(string? value)
    {
        const string name = nameof(Party.Guests);
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? MakeBlank(name) : new NamedSet(name, value);
    }

    public static NamedSet MakeDrinks(string? value)
    {
        const string name = nameof(Party.Drinks);
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? MakeBlank(name) : new NamedSet(name, value);
    }
    
    public static NamedSet MakeBlank(string name)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? new NamedSet("", "") : new NamedSet(name, "");
    }
    
}

and the way I use it is that when I have a list of my Party objects or other classes objects, I can call it call this:
p.MakeDrinks(p.Drinks)

I even have another class say House with say properties like
public record House
{
    public string? Windows{ get; set; }
    public string? Doors{ get; set; }
    public string? Carpets{ get; set; }
}

then again I have to go to my NamedSet and add a method like this:
public static NamedSet MakeDoors(string? value)
{
    const string name = nameof(House.Doors);
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? MakeBlank(name) : new NamedSet(name, value);
}

public static NamedSet MakeCarpets(string? value)
{
    const string name = nameof(House.Carpets);
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? MakeBlank(name) : new NamedSet(name, value);
}

You see there is a bunch of similr code. How can I make it better?

Are you looking for a way to simply reduce the repetitive code or do you want to have a single generic Make method?

@PeterCsala either of those is an improvement and I appreciate it

State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.

Reduce the repetitive code

Extract the repetitive code into a dedicated method

private static NamedSet Make(string name, string? value)
  => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? MakeBlank(name) : new NamedSet(name, value);


Use it everywhere

public static NamedSet MakeLocation(string? value)
 => Make(nameof(Party.Location), value);

public static NamedSet MakeGuests(string? value)
 => Make(nameof(Party.Guests), value);

...

Single generic Make method

Use property selector and reflection

private static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertySelector)
    => ((MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body).Member.Name;

public static NamedSet Make<TSource, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertySelector, string? value)
{
   string name = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);
   return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? MakeBlank(name) : new NamedSet(name, value);
}


Use it

_ = Make<Party, string>(p => p.Location, "");

